# Adding WMTSLayer from service to ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, wmts

I want to add all the layers in my WMTS service to ArcMap using ArcObjects, but I am able to get only one layer.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What is the service URL that you are using to try and access this WMTS?

Comment: @PolyGeo I want to add it to my ArcMap through ArcObjetcs. Thanks for your reply. I have solved the issue at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for adding all layers at ones, as well as a particular layer to ArcMap:

```cs
public static void GetWMTSLayer(string url = "http://IP-Address:Port/Service/rest/services/OSM/MapServer/WMTS")
{
        IProperySet propSet= new PropertySetClass();
        propSet.SetProperty("URL",url);
        IWMTSConnectionFactory wmtsConnFactory=new WMTSConnectionFactoryClass();
        IWMTSConnection wmtsConnection=wmtsConnFactory.Open(propSet,0,null);
        IWMTSServiceDescription wmtsServceDescriotion=wmtsConnection as IWMTSServiceDescription ;
        for(int i=0;i< wmtsServceDescriotion.LayerDescriptionCount;i++)
        {
            IWMTSLayerDescription layerDescription=wmtsServceDescriotion.getLayerDescription(i);
            IWMTSLayer wmtsLayer=new WMTSLayerClass();

            IPropertySet propSet_1=new PropertySetClass();
            propSet_1.SetProperty("URL", url);
            propSet_1.SetProperty("LayerName",layerDescription.Identifier);

            WMTSConnectionName connectonName= new WMTSConnectionNameClass();
            connectionName.ConnectionProperties=propSet_1;
            wmtsLayer.Connect((IName)connectionName);
                addData(wmtslayer);
        }
}

public static void addData(IWMTSLayer wmtslayer)
{
    IMap pMap=(IMap)((IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document).FocusMap);
    ILayer pLayer=new FeatureLayer();

    pLayer=(ILayer)wmtslayer;
    pMap.AddLayer(pLayer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Toggle Contents Panel button you will see a new space at the bottom of the Catalog view. From there you can choose several layers

Comment: Actually I have added them manually I want to add it through ArcObjects. Thanks for your reply @Daniel.   I have solved the issue.